# Column Sorting with PROC Transpose in SAS

Tags: sas

I am using below mentioned code to get the columns sorted dynamically after proc transpose. I have gone a lot of solutions for this solution. But now I am getting an error if I run

```
data work.AB ;
input name $ class $ dt $ gpa $;
datalines;
JOHN 1 201607 C-
JOHN 1 201608 C+
JOHN 1 201702 B-
JOHN 2 201608 A
NICK 1 201608 A
NICK 1 201707 A
MIKE 2 201608 B
MIKE 2 201607 B
MIKE 2 201707 B+
MIKE 2 201702 B
BOB 3 201702 D
BOB 3 201607 C
BOB 3 201707 C
;
proc sort data=work.AB;
by NAME ClASS dt;
run;

PROC TRANSPOSE DATA = AB OUT = ABC(drop=_name_) ;
BY nAME cLASS; 
VAR GPA;
ID dt; 
RUN ;

proc sql ;
create table test as 
select name into : list separated by ' '
from dictionary.columns
where libname='WORK' and memname='ABC'
order by input(substr(name,anydigit(name)),best32.)
;
quit;

%put &list;

data want;
retain &list;
set ABC;
run;
```

Error that I get is

```
22 GOPTIONS ACCESSIBLE;
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference LIST not resolved.
23 %put &list;
&list

24 data want;
25 retain &list;
_
22
200
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference LIST not resolved.

ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a name, ;, _ALL_, _CHARACTER_, _CHAR_, _NUMERIC_.
ERROR 200-322: The symbol is not recognized and will be ignored.

26 set ABC;
27 run;
```

Kindly suggest.

Comment: You need to give more information (presumably, the log from the first part of the program).  The SQL SELECT INTO bit isn't working, for whatever reason, but we don't know why.

Comment: I just mentioned that Error log, which I was getting. Rest everything is working fine for me.
I am not able to find solution to the mentioned error.
Perhaps you can use
proc sql noprint;
select name into : list separated by ' '
from dictionary.columns
where libname=WORK' and memname='ABC'
order by input(substr(name,anydigit(name)),best32.)
quit;

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put the values from the same SELECT statement into both a dataset and macro variables. Remove the `create table test as` from your SQL code.

You also might want to suppress some of the warnings by changing the query to:

```
proc sql noprint ;
select case when (not anydigit(name)) then -1
            else input(substr(name,anydigit(name)),?32.)
       end as order
     , name
  into :list
     , :list separated by ' '
from dictionary.columns
where libname='WORK' and memname='ABC'
order by 1
;
quit;

%put &list;
```

Comment: HI Tom, I tried doing same. But I am getting same error which I have mentioned in the query earlier.

68         data want;
69           retain &list;
NOTE: Line generated by the macro variable "LIST".
69          class name 201607 201608 201702 201707
                              ______
                              22
                              200
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a name, ;, _ALL_, _CHARACTER_, _CHAR_, _NUMERIC_.  

ERROR 200-322: The symbol is not recognized and will be ignored.
 which I am not able to resolve

Comment: Either your variable names are not following normal conventions and so you need to specify `nliteral(name)` in the query. Or else you did not specify the `INTO` clause properly and you have ended up with the values of `ORDER` into the macro variable `LIST` instead of the values of `NAME`..